# how to insert unicode data into table with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My database config file is set to

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

but every time i insert Unicode Characters, they are insert as **?????** question marks.

my mysql database info as

```
Type : MyISAM
Collation : latin1_swedish_ci
```

any idea what im doing wrong and how to fix the issue?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem mostly with your database collation, you must make it utf-8 since your

```
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

is not the same as your database collation.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an incompatibility between the scripts and the db, so...

Make sure your html content has:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

In your config/config.php, insure you have:

```
$config['charset'] = "UTF-8";
```

The latin1_swedish_ci collation should mostly be ok, but a utf8 collation would be better.

Answer (score 0):

simply change database column Collation type to 
"utf8_general_ci"   .
this will support all languages.